# GitLab issue with porting bash script to CI Job

Tags: regex, bash, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a bash script which I can use to test a tag against regex.

Attempted to port it as a Gitlab-CI job, but all tags are being recognized as invalid.

The bash script below works as expected for all cases

```bash
#!/bin/bash

VERSION_REGEX="^v(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)((-(alpha|beta|rc)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))|((-(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?-[0-9]{14}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}))?$"

# Iterate over the array and echo each version (array in examples below)
for CI_COMMIT_TAG in "${versions[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" =~ $VERSION_REGEX ]]; then 
        echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    else 
        echo "Invalid tag format: $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    fi
done
```

The following my attempt to port it as a Gitlab CI Job:

```yaml
stages:
  - validate

variables:
  VERSION_REGEX: >
    ^v(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)((-(alpha|beta|rc)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))|((-(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?-[0-9]{14}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}))?$

validate_tag:
  stage: validate
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" # Run this job when a tag is created manually or added through the UI at Code > Tags
  script:
    - echo $VERSION_REGEX
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" =~ $VERSION_REGEX ]]; then 
        echo "Valid tag format: $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      else 
        echo "Invalid tag format: $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
        exit 1
      fi
```

Versions tested against: (feel free to try here: https://onlinegdb.com/dJqjG-jj1)

```bash
# Declare the array with version strings
versions=(
    # Valid
    "v0.0.0"
    "v1.2.3"
    "v11.22.33"
    "v0.1.6-alpha.0"
    "v0.1.2-alpha.0"
    "v0.1.2-alpha.3"
    "v1.2.3-beta.45"
    "v23.34.45-rc.567"
    "v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c"
    "v0.0.0-5-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c"
    # Invalid
    "0"
    "V0"
    "v1"
    "v000"
    "v1.9"
    "v.1.9"
    "v1.90"
    "v1.090"
    "v00.00.00"
    "v01.02.03"
    "v1.9-alpha.2"
    "v0.1.2-alpha.03"
    "v1.2.3-beta-hardcoded.4"
    "v0.0.0-5-20170915032832-14c0d48eaxyz"
    "vX.Y.Z-C-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c"
    "v0.0.0-5-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c-modified"
)
```

Examples from the output of using the Gitlab Runner:

- Expected Valid

```bash
$ echo $VERSION_REGEX
^v(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)((-(alpha|beta|rc)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))|((-(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?-[0-9]{14}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}))?$
$ if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" =~ $VERSION_REGEX ]]; then  # collapsed multi-line command
Invalid tag format: v0.1.6-alpha.0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

- Expected Invalid

```bash
$ echo $VERSION_REGEX
^v(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)((-(alpha|beta|rc)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))|((-(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?-[0-9]{14}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}))?$
$ if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" =~ $VERSION_REGEX ]]; then  # collapsed multi-line command
Invalid tag format: v0.1.6-alpha.invalid
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

*Hate that the title is vague, willing to change it; also let me know what else I can provide to make it easier to identify the issue...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by using grep instead to perform the check. Could not figure out how to resolve the native bash check, but for my use case, using `coreutils` is acceptable.

```yaml
script:
    - |
      result=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | grep -oE "$VERSION_REGEX")
      if [ -n "$result" ]; then
        echo "Valid tag format: $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      else 
        echo "Invalid tag format: $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
        exit 1
      fi
```